# Hotkeys for scrolling

Tags: windows, hotkeys

Does Windows have any hotkeys for scrolling in a window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the application, *UP*, *DOWN*, *LEFT*, *RIGHT*, *PAGE UP* and *PAGE DOWN* will move the contents of a window.  Sometimes you may need to use one of those keys in combination with *CTRL* to scroll the window.

*CTRL+HOME* typically scrolls to the top of the window.
*CTRL+END* typically scrolls to the bottom of a window.

Comment: And you probably can coax AHK into sending WM_SCROLL messages to a window on pressing a key to emulate mousewheel scrolling behavior.